# Migrating Windows 2008 R2 to Windows 2012 (migrate all FSMO too)

Tags: windows, migration, domain-controller

I own 2 server with Windows 2008 R2, both DC. The first one is of course the Primary DC (with all FSMO). What I would like to do is ro dcdemote the 2nd DC, remove it from domain and replace the Windows 2008 r2 with 2012. I will then rejoin this 2nd DC (with the new 2012 server) to domain and dcpromo it (Server Management). After this is a new DC I would like to temporary transfer all the FSMO to this server, while I'm doing the same operation on what is actually the Primary DC.

Is this a stupid solution? What I would like to do is a clean installation, I don't want to upgrade directly those systems.

Suggestions? Ideas?
Thanks,
Mauro

Comment: This is the typical path when upgrading domain controllers in the domain. You cannot do an in-place upgrade anyway. Do you have any **specific** concerns? As is, it is not that much of a question to answer.

Comment: Thanks dude. Well, actually... I would like to know how to transfer FSMO from primary DC (2008R2) to a new DC (Win 2012), and then bring them back to the primary DC, in the while upgraded from 2008R2 to 2012.

Answer (score 2):

This is the typical path when upgrading domain controllers in the domain. Contrary to my previous claim in the comment, there *is* an in-place upgrade path from Windows Server 2008 (R2). The procedure is quite similar to introducing a 2008 DC into a 2003 domain, the best place to start is [***the Technet documentation***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994618.aspx). Check the prerequisites ([forest functional level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730985.aspx), recommended hotfix when running under Hyper-V) and follow the walk-throughs from the [official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574134.aspx) or third parties.

- http://greigmitchell.co.uk/guide-migrating-server-2008-r2-domain-controllers-to-server-2012/
- http://kpytko.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/adding-first-windows-server-2012-domain-controller-within-windows-200320082008r2-network/

Transferring FSMO levels is just the same as has been before - just [use ntdsutil](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255504/en-us) from either DC.